# how to update the column data based on the given select statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
UPDATE SQ_DEAL_PARTNER SET PRIMARY_FL =PRIMARYFL WHERE  DPID =
    (SELECT DPID, MIN(CASE WHEN DPID IN (SELECT MIN(DPID) 
     FROM SQ_DEAL_PARTNER  WHERE DID=17664 )THEN  'Y' ELSE 'N' END)PRIMARYFL 
    FROM sq_deal_partner dl 
    WHERE DID=17664
     AND PARTNER_TY = 'D'
    GROUP BY DPID);
```

how can i update above that statement please help in this.

This my query i want output like this

```
dpid    primary_fl
123      y
124      n
125      n
```

Comment: When you post, you generally need to show four things. You posted two of them, please add the other two. They are: (1) A description of your base table or tables (table name, column name(s) and data types, only for the columns involved in solving the problem), and some sample data. (2) A clear statement of the requirement - the logic to be used. (3) How the output should look. (4) What you have tried. Now: you posted (3) and (4), we still need (1) and (2).

Comment: @mathguy i need to update the primary_fl based on the min(dpid) .if suppose min(dpid) then primary_fl='Y' elseprimary_fl= 'N'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use half merge statment:

```
MERGE INTO SQ_DEAL_PARTNER dest
USING (SELECT DPID, 
              MIN(CASE 
                   WHEN DPID IN (SELECT MIN(DPID) 
                                   FROM SQ_DEAL_PARTNER  
                                  WHERE DID=17664 )
                   THEN 'Y' 
                   ELSE 'N' 
                  END) PRIMARYFL 
         FROM sq_deal_partner dl 
        WHERE DID=17664
          AND PARTNER_TY = 'D'
        GROUP BY DPID) src
ON (src.DPID = dest.DPID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET
dest.PRIMARY_FL = src.PRIMARYFL;
```

Comment: is there any possible method.could you please provide me.thanks

Comment: thanks for quick replay .but is there any easiest method?

Comment: I'll try, but sorry for my eng :) Think about dest and src like a two difrent  tables. Dest is your destanation and you need find in source(src) table matched rows that is writen in ON condition. Just You need to do is prepare src SELECT to uptade correct rows.
Look here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_rittman_merge.htm
MERGE is wery useful tool and it is ease to understand ;)

Comment: is it possible to used with in package?or any issue will occurred at execution time?thanks

Comment: Shure, MERGE is a standard SQL instruction in Oracle like Insert or Update. You can use it in packages/functions/procedures.